# Provide SSL certificate to SQL Server via JDBC

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

The [Microsoft JDBC SSL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16) details the use of a Java keystore in order to specify a certificate bundle to use when validating the TLS connection. Is there a way to provide a certificate bundle without needing to store it within a JKS when connecting to a SQL Server database? [Postgres](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) seems to have a `sslrootcert` option which appears to be lacking for SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 6.3.3 the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL allows, to specify a custom implementation of `javax.net.ssl.TrustManager` through connection [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver16#properties). You can specify a class name and a constructor parameter (e.g. a file name or the certificate in PEM format).

See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/Custom-TrustManager), for more detailed instructions and a simple example of a custom TrustManager. The functionality of the `sslrootcert` option of the Postgres driver is implemented in a similar way [here](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/ssl/LibPQFactory.java#L142).